# How to pass parameter to a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question which at the first glance might seem to be stupid. I got problem figuring it out and whenever I use it, nothing really happens. I have a plugin in jQuery written by myself which is like this:

```
(function(){
$.fn.myPlugin = function(options){
var options = $.extend({
firstParameter : null;
}
// the rest of the plugin
})(jQuery)
```

But when I call it from an HTML file, like this: `("#object").myPlugin(2);`, it fails to work (note the parameter that I have passed). But if I skip the argument and call it like this: `("#object").myPlugin();`, it all works. What is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, `options` is meant to be an object, and you're not extending anything... Double check the manual again, you're missing something.

Comment: you overwrite `options` in the first line.

Answer (score 30):

You want this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        myPlugin: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                something: 23,
                otherThing: 'hello'
            };

            options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            console.log(options.something);
            console.log(options.otherThing);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Now this should work to override the `something` option (don't forget to pass an **object**):

```
$('#object').myPlugin({something: 17});
```

Comment: Accepting my answer would be better than thanking me in a comment.

Comment: Oops! it is possible when my reputation rises above 15

Comment: Isn't it best practice to omit the `var` when setting the `optionns` variable a second time? `options =  $.extend(defaults, options);`

Answer (score 0):

You define a function with no parameter function() {} then you pass the jQuery to it. It may be the cause of problem.

```
(function(){
  // nothing is the $ here
  $.fn.myPlugin = function(options){
    var options = $.extend({
     firstParameter : null;
    }
  // the rest of the plugin
 })(jQuery)
```

You should change to

```
(function($) {})(jQuery)
```

and I think it will work. Hope this help